# React.js: Example in tutorial not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing the React.js tutorial from http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html. Here are my files:

template.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello React</title>
        <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.8.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.8.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/jsx" src='tut.js'>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and tut.js:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var data = [
    {author: 'Tldr', text: 'This is a comment'}
]

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='commentBox'>
                <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList data={this.props.data} />
                <CommentForm />
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
                    return <Comment author={comment.author}>{comment.text}</Comment>
            })
        return (
            <div className='commentList'>
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='commentForm'>
                Hello World, I am a comment
            </div>
        )
    }
})

var Comment = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className='comment'>
                <h2 className='commentAuthor'>
                    {this.props.author}
                </h2>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
})

React.renderComponent(
    <CommentBox data={data} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
)
```

But when I open it in the browser, I just see a blank page without any comments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any messages in the browser's js console?

Comment: I get the following error in the console: 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/jashua/Desktop/code/react/tut.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.' When I paste the js inside the script tags, everything works fine. How do I get around the cross origin error?

Comment: I don't get it, none of the answers are so much a solution. No tutorial, blog or an example mentions how to just a simple example working on your machine when in the end you it has to be served. Also the console prints "use the react dev tools" but I cant

Comment: Added a bounty for a **Concise, standard approach** to getting started with a simple react example **off my machine where I know what files I need to point too. (Not off codepen or some complicated npm module setup). What is the simplest bare bones setup. so one can understand how it all fits.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Chrome doesn't let you load `file://` urls via XHR (which as mentioned elsewhere is how the in browser transform works). You have a couple options:

- Use a different browser. I know Firefox works.
- Start a local web server (Python ships with one, so if you have that installed it's very simple - http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python).
- Put the script inline instead of in a separate file. That's doable for something simple like this but you'll want to try one of the other options as your code gets more complicated.

Comment: Python server tip helped!

Answer (score 5):

The following command works for me. But before the command, you may need to stop chrome process anyhow, can be from task manager.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Second way, you can also use **--allow-file-access-from-files** flag in the chrome shortcut properties. But this is recommended only for developing purpose.

Answer (score 4):

JSXTransformer tries to load the source using ajax. This will not work for `file://` paths.

This means that you should either serve your small project using a HTTP server (apache, grunt connect etc.) OR put your script source directly in the script tag.

Answer (score 3):

For chrome, you can try to disable the origin checking, more details can be found in [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome). Of course, only use this for development.

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason a local webserver doesn't appear to be enough for this on Chrome. Using Python 3.4 and viewing my site through `http://localhost:8000` I was getting the following error:

> Redirect at origin 'https://fb.me' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

...which is strange considering the Babel script included in the tutorial wasn't giving the same error.

I was able to get around this by removing the `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes on the `script` tag used to load react and react-dom, changing:

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-zTm/dblzLXQNp3CgY+hfaC/WJ6h4XtNrePh2CW2+rO9GPuNiPb9jmthvAL+oI/dQ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ntqCsHbLdMxT352UbhPbT7fqjE8xi4jLmQYQa8mYR+ylAapbXRfdsDweueDObf7m"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on #2 from *Paul O'Shannessy's* answer.

The nice solution is :

If you have python2.x:

```
$ cd /myreact-project/htmlfiles/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

For python3.x

```
$ cd /myreact-project/htmlfiles/
$ python -m http.server
```

You can then point your browser to `http://192.168.1.2:8000/<myfile.html>` or where ever the python module is serving your files and use it from any browser without hassles.

Answer (score -3):

I crete [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4vge/2/) with your code, and its work. A think, try to move your scripts from `head` to before `tut.js`.
Also, don't forget `key` property in list render component. I added it to Fiddle.

Comment: It's a local issue, the problem isn't demonstrable on JSFiddle.