# XMLHttpRequest; Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

When I try to do a ajax call, I got the error on chrome below.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:;. Cross origin requests are
>   only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Here is code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {pvalue : pid},
    cache: false,
    url: "xxx.in/yy/ajax.php",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
    }
```

Comment: is your ajax.php inside your project or you are calling outside project page ?

Comment: try without `http:` directly provide directory and page name

Comment: I have changed it , but I got the same error @AmeyDeshpande

Comment: share your path to the file you are accessing from that call

Comment: There's something you're not showing us about your actual URL for the ajax request.  The error msg makes it sound like the URL is not actually of the form `http://somedomain.com`,

Comment: url: "http://xxx.in/yy/ajax.php",

Comment: Here's a guess.  Is the web page itself that the script is in running on a localhost: or file: URL?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is in the same project , same domain , same folder and same server

Comment: That's not what I'm asking.   When you get this error, what is the EXACT URL in the URL bar of the browser.  The error says that the URL is something unusual that does not permit cross-origin requests.  You need to show us what both the full URL of the page is and the full URL of the ajax call.  The browser is complaining about the match between these two so withholding that info from us will not help anyone give you an answer.

Comment: Why are you not providing the info asked for in the above comment?  The error implies that your situation has something to do with the two URLs (page URL and ajax URL).  We can't do much more to help without seeing those actual URLs.

Answer (score 5):

All research into that specific error message suggests that the host web page is not being loading via an http:// URL and is probably a file: URL.  The browser will not, by default, permit cross origin requests from a file: URL.

You need to load the web page through your web server, not via the file system if you want to use ajax requests.

Here are some other questions and answers about that specific error that all point to the wrong type of URL being used to load the page.

["Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP." error when loading a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

[React.js: Example in tutorial not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904098/react-js-example-in-tutorial-not-working)

[Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP but it's not cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449716/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-but-its-not-cross-domain)

http://answers.playcanvas.com/questions/833/cannot-load-model-due-to-cross-origin-request-being-blocked

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tincr-for-chrome-devtools/nA9k2qh7F-g

Comment: I have already done all of them

Comment: @DurgeshPandey - done all of what?

Comment: yes sir most of them i tried

Comment: Upvoted for demonstrating undeserved patience!

Comment: How do I load the web page through my web server? I don't understand the distinction.

Comment: @nirvanaswap - Please don't co-opt someone else's question into your situation.  If you need help with your specific situation, then please write your own question and describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing data from other domains, you have to override Chrome's `Same-origin Policy`. For that you have to specify `dataType: 'jsonp'`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {pvalue : pid},
    cache: false,
    url: "xxx.in/yy/ajax.php",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
    }
});
```

If the file `ajax.php` in your server (the one which you are working now), you can simply specify the file name in `url` section (as below).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {pvalue : pid},
    cache: false,
    url: "ajax.php",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $modal.find('.edit-content').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This issue does not align with the specific error message the OP is getting.  This is not a generic cross origin issue, it's something different than generic.