# Jquery load content of another page

Tags: jquery, html

I trying to load content from another page but there are error shown when i click "get content" button , here the script >>

```js
$(function(){
$('#get_contect').click(function(){
$('#contect').load('page.html #pageContect');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<header>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</header>
<button type="button" id="get_contect">get contect</button>
<body>
<div id = "contect">
</div>
</body>

<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

the error that shown is :

> jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/khaled%20salem/Desktop/New%20folder/page.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You run your code over `file:///` protocol

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041656/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-file-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-ht

Comment: Have you enabled CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' enabled on your resource you are requesting ?

Comment: ooops it not enabled

Comment: @KhaledALHajSalem see the first comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest; Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578707/xmlhttprequest-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-h)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the page to load, it is needed for the loaded file to be in the same domain, which can be done by hosting your website locally, using one of these apps:

- [MAMP: easy to configure, available for Windows and Mac OS X](https://www.mamp.info/en/)
- [XAMPP: more advanced, available for Windows, OS X and Linux](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)
- [WAMP: in the mid of the two, but not very user-friendly and available only for Windows](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

You will **not** need to enable CORS as the file requested is from the same domain, namely from localhost (or your hosted website when deployed).

After you have configured your host, change the URL of the request to the following:

```
$('#contect').load('page.html#pageContect');
```

This means the page is in the same folder as your current page, and the `#pageContect` element will be shown after it is loaded - you must have no space in between.

If you have page in another folder, you can either use the absolute path of your website directory by entering the trailing slash at beginning (i.e. `$('#contect').load('/path/to/file/page.html#pageContect');`, either by providing a relative one from the location of your file, using `./` to go up the directory.