# Cordova throwing exception Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: android, html, eclipse, cordova, droidgap

I am very new to Cordova framework. I am trying to access HTML file from Droidgap activity, but getting exception as,

```
Cross-origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

For this I found one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578707/xmlhttprequest-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-h), maybe you will find this question as a duplicate, but I am looking for Android solution, they are saying to install local server and then try to access this HTML, but in my case I want it to be accessible in MainActivity.

following is code..

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); //this line throws nullPointerException for appView
        super.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        super.appView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/MyHtml.html");
    }
}
```

My HTML is located at asset/www/MyHtml.html

I am really struggling with this issue, can anyone help to get out of this?

Comment: You are missing super.init(); to setup the appView variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> Cross-origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

You also say (in comment):

> In this case I am getting appView variable as null,
>   NullpointerException

First get the appView with the getView() method, and use a local variable:

```
WebView myappView    = getView();//getView is a method from DroidGap super class
WebSettings settings = myappView.getSettings();
```

Your are not initializing `DroidGap` so add `super.init();` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();//you were missing this
    WebView myappView    = getView();//getView is a method from DroidGap super class
    WebSettings settings = myappView.getSettings();
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true); //this line throws nullPointerException for appView
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/MyHtml.html");
    }
}
```

You should be fine now but you can also try one (or all) of these (see [WebSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)):

```
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
```

See [DroidGap.java](https://github.com/sintaxi/phonegap/blob/master/android/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java) source code.

Comment: In this case  I am getting appView variable as null, NullpointerException

Comment: @Tushar Digambar Deshpande Why did you not put that in the question ? See my updated answer

Comment: Sorry about that, but even after adding above line i.e. for getView() not working throwing same NullPointerException. It says that there is no such a method in super (i.e. in Droidgap class)