# Ignore http:localhost from ajax url

Tags: ajax, django, django-channels

Im using django channels for implementing instant messaging app in my project.The message box does not take up th entire screen ,so im trying to implement it using ajax.The problem im facing is that in my url field in the ajax is prepending with http://locahost .I dont want this since im using ASGI and django channels with ws://

I have tried prepending the url with a "/"

```
var wsStart = 'ws://';
if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
    wsStart ='wss://';
 }
var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:"/"+endpoint+"/messages/"+username+"/",
  data: {
  'username': username,
   csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
   },
   success: function (res, status) {
    console.log("RESOPONSE",res);
    },
    error: function (res) {
    console.log(res.status);
   }
  });
```

I want the url to be ws://localhost:8000/messages/

what i get now is
http://localhost:8000/ws://localhost:8000/messages/mohitharshan123/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you start the url with "/", and that means the current base url on whish you append other path. Specify the url first ws://localhost and after append what you want.

Comment: it does the same after removing the "/"

Comment: Add the url string without parameters, hard string, and it must work.

Comment: Sorry..Now it works but now im stuck with another error  jquery-latest.js:9631 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'ws://localhost:8000/messages/mohitharshan123/' from origin 'htttp://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Set allowed hosts and cors in django settings.

Comment: allowed hosts has already been set to '*'   .For the cors should i install django-cors-headers?

Comment: Yes, install it, sorry I can not help you more because I am on mobile.

Comment: its ok ..Thanks

Comment: i installed it and added middleware and CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True
.still same error

Comment: maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578707/xmlhttprequest-cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-protocol-schemes-h

Comment: It is connecting using jsonp and the messages get sent once.But when i open anotherconnection i get this error:Uncaught INVALID_STATE_ERR : Pausing to reconnect websocket..I cant receive any updates after this unless i refresh my tab.

Comment: since im using ajax ,how can i maintain a webocket connection to the url

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't use WebSocket with AJAX or CORS, it won't work.

Comment: please tell me any other way to implement this then

Comment: Just create the web socket I don't see where the problem is even if the message box doesn't take the entire screen